# Create FTP client on windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I need to request a FTP server in my app to get a list of file. But I can't find any way to succed it !! Since FtpWebRequest is not supported by windows phone 8.1, I don't know what to use.

Am I suppose tu use WebRequest class ? I try with this code :

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("ftp://192.168.1.103/Users:22");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ippon", "ippon");
```

but it give me this error :

```
Error : System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
at System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Uri requestUri, Boolean schemeOnly)
at System.Net.WebRequest.Create(String requestUriString)
at HidTestSdk.DataModel.XmlDataSource.<GetXmlDataAsync>d__c.MoveNext()
```

And when I try to use FtpWebRequest, this is what I got :

```
The type or namespace name 'FtpWebRequest' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Visual Studio does not Suggest any class, just "Generate class for FtpWebRequest"

Comment: This _might_ work with Windows Phone: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-SocketsFtp-4fc23b33

Comment: I already saw this, but for some reason I need to use only my own code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `FTPWebRequest`.

```
FtpWebRequest request = FtpWebRequest.Create(adress) as FtpWebRequest;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
```

Comment: I edited my question with the result of FtpWebRequest  when I try to use it.

Comment: I'm sorry, you can't use the FptWebRequest class at Windows Phone Apps. This may help you https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CSWindowsStoreAppFTPDownloa-88a90bd9

Comment: So now I'm trying to use this example. Have you already used it ? because I'm not sure about how to use it and which function I should call (and in which order...)

Comment: I manage to use it but I forgot to precise that I actually need a SFTP connection... I think this library doesn't support it.